# How to get from a subscriptions data to transactional data in Tableau?

Tags: python, sql, excel, tableau-api, saas

I have a chunk of data with subscriptions looking as following:

```
customer_name    start_date   end_date     subscription_amount
A                1-7-2017     31-10-2017   4 USD/month
B                1-8-2017     30-09-2017   2 USD/month
C                1-10-2017    30-11-2017   3 USD/month
```

I need to convert it to transactional data, so the end result should look as following:

```
customer_name    payment_date    amount
A                1-7-2017        4 USD
A                1-8-2017        4 USD
A                1-9-2017        4 USD
A                1-10-2017       4 USD
B                1-8-2017        2 USD
B                1-9-2017        2 USD
C                1-10-2017       3 USD
C                1-11-2017       3 USD
```

I need to do this conversion to run the analysis in Tableau, but Excel solutions are also acceptable. I do not want to do it manually, rather I am looking for automated solution with SQL or Python (I am new to both of those)

Comment: There are a variety of ways to accomplish this in Tableau https://community.tableau.com/thread/151387

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python *(you need a little format your data to match exactly with your Question, but the idea is here)* http://rextester.com/OENHUT92986

use this comprehensive list `listMonths = [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-01") for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=dtstart, until=until)` to list every first day of each month between 2 date.

```
import datetime
import time
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY


data=[
      {"customer_name":"A" ,"start_date":"2017-07-01","end_date":"2017-10-31","subscription_amount":"4 USD/month"},
      {"customer_name":"B" ,"start_date":"2017-08-01","end_date":"2017-09-30","subscription_amount":"2 USD/month"},
      {"customer_name":"C" ,"start_date":"2017-10-01","end_date":"2017-11-30","subscription_amount":"3 USD/month"}
     ]

for datum in data :
    dtstart=parser.parse(datum["start_date"])
    until=parser.parse(datum["end_date"])

    listMonths = [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-01") for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=dtstart, until=until)]

    for month in listMonths :    
         print datum["customer_name"],month,datum["subscription_amount"]
```

will produce :

```
A 2017-07-01 4 USD/month
A 2017-08-01 4 USD/month
A 2017-09-01 4 USD/month
A 2017-10-01 4 USD/month
B 2017-08-01 2 USD/month
B 2017-09-01 2 USD/month
C 2017-10-01 3 USD/month
C 2017-11-01 3 USD/month
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution however is limited to cases when I have the date starting not at 1st, but at the 30, 31st etc., so I have adjusted it with a different loop:

`for datum in invoices_data :
    days = (datum["End Date"] - datum["Start Date"]).days
    diff_months = int(round(days / 30,0))

    for i in range(0, diff_months):
        month = datum["Start Date"] + relativedelta(months=i)
        print datum["customer_name"],month,datum["subscription_amount"]`

Comment: Thanks man, I have really solved the problem because you helped me with the way of thinking. We can close it.

Comment: cannot do it atm due to lack of reputation :-(

Answer (score 0):

**Here a  Query in MS-SQL**

if object_id('tempdb..#subscriptions') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #subscriptions
if object_id('tempdb..#Calendar') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Calendar

declare @min_date as date
declare @max_date as date

create table #subscriptions
(
   customer_name char,
   startdate date,
   end_date  date,
   subscription_amount money,
   currencyPeriod varchar(10)
)

create table #Calendar
(
    Date_f date
)

insert into #subscriptions  values('A',CAST('2017-7-01 00:00:00.000' as date),CAST('2017-07-10 00:00:00.000' as date),4,'USD/month')
insert into #subscriptions values('B',CAST('2017-8-01 00:00:00.000' as date),CAST('2017-08-04 00:00:00.000' as date),2,'USD/month')
insert into #subscriptions  values('C',CAST('2017-10-01 00:00:00' as date),CAST('2017-10-02 00:00:00.000' as date),3,'USD/month')

---here we need to get the MIN and MAX date of all register
set @min_date = (select MIN(startdate) FROM #subscriptions)
set @max_date = (select MAX(end_date) FROM #subscriptions)

--Here we Create a Temp Calendar respect of the min and max date of all register

WHILE @min_date <= @max_date
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #Calendar (Date_f)
  SELECT @min_date

SET @min_date = DATEADD(day, 1,@min_date)
END

--FINAL RESULT
SELECT B.customer_name,A.Date_f as 'payment_date',
CONCAT(CAST(subscription_amount as int),' ','USD') as 'subscription_amount'
FROM #Calendar A
INNER JOIN #subscriptions B
ON A.Date_f BETWEEN startdate AND end_date

Comment: Thanks, this one seems to be the most complicated, so I prefer to use Excel raw data and Python script solution